# Lightweight PWA framework

Tags: angularjs, raspberry-pi, progressive-web-apps, ionic-v1, mpd

I am implementing a PWA for a speaker system.

The idea is to have a RaspberryPi running on the system and clients connecting via Wifi to the Pi. This will show a captive portal with instructions to install the PWA on the homescreen. With the PWA the user can control the music (talking to [mpd](https://www.musicpd.org/) via [Websockify](https://github.com/kanaka/websockify) running on the Pi) and other features such as lights.

I've already tried [OnsenUI](https://onsen.io/)+[Angular](https://angularjs.org/) as I like the idea of a native looking App. However, it ended up being a bit buggy and not delivering an App-like experience on all devices. I know Ionic has done a lot of work on their [PWA framework](https://ionicframework.com/pwa) recently. And they also recommend [Stencil](https://stenciljs.com/) - however as far as I understand stenciljs will render on the server side. As I'm running on a RaspberryPi with limited ressources that might not be the best solution.

Therefore my question is: Does anyone know a good lightweight framework to create a PWA (client side rendering). I don't really need the offline capabilities such as service workers as the App will only work when connected to the speaker. However, I would like to ensure that as much as possible will be cached to reduce the load on the RaspberryPi.

Many thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need some more clarity on what PWA is. You are saying you don't need Service workers, but wanted to cache as much as possible. Service workers are the very thing in PWA, which does caching.

From your "Client side rendering" next to PWA, I'm guessing you are trying to mean client side rendering using PWA, which I'm not sure what you mean by.

Having manifest.json to enable add to home screen and service worker to cache and work in offline mode are the main aspects of PWA and not sure what you are trying to do with PWA without these aspects.